# GSON: Help me parse some unknown JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Hi have JSON data that can come back with different data so I am writing  deserialiser to parse  it

So basically it come as  this

```
{
  "data": {
    "errors": {
      "user": [
        "Invalid email, username or password. Please try again"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

OR this

```
{
  "errors": {
    "promotion": [
      "The code was invalid"
    ]
  }
}
```

My goal is to extract the strings in the array, I do not know what the field will be called. All I do know is that it come as Data or errors or both then inside I have a unknown field name with an array of messages.

So I wrote a deserialiser

```
 @Override
    public APIErrorBody deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String message = ""; /** The error message we are going to display */

        /** Backend inconsistency: Unsuccessful response from backend can come with node data -> or errors -> we must check what is there */
        JsonObject dataOrErrorsAsRoot = json.getAsJsonObject().get("data").getAsJsonObject();
        if(dataOrErrorsAsRoot == null){ //If we do not have data node then lets check for errors
            dataOrErrorsAsRoot = json.getAsJsonObject().get("errors").getAsJsonObject();
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : dataOrErrorsAsRoot.entrySet())
        {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            JsonElement element = entry.getValue();
            DebugUtils.Log(key + " " + element.toString());
            if(element.isJsonArray()){
                JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i ++){
                    message +=  jsonArray.get(i).getAsString() + "\n";
                }
            }
        }


        APIErrorBody apiErrorBody = new APIErrorBody();
        apiErrorBody.setErrorMessageToDisplay(message);
        DebugUtils.Log("the final message is " + apiErrorBody.getErrorMessageToDisplay());
        return apiErrorBody;
    }
```

The problem I have is here

```
  for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : dataOrErrorsAsRoot.entrySet())
            {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                JsonElement element = entry.getValue();
                DebugUtils.Log(key + " " + element.toString());
                if(element.isJsonArray()){
                    JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i ++){
                        message +=  jsonArray.get(i).getAsString() + "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
```

So the problem is, its not a JSON array even though when I debug, it is. The value contained in the JsonElement 'element' is

```
{"user":["Invalid email, username or password. Please try again"]}
```

Which is an array

However, my debugger says this which confuses me a lot o_O

[image]

That element is a JSON object that contains a LinkedTreeMap
And that map has a value which a JSON array, how do I get it :)

Someone please help, I am dying

Comment: why you do not check whether the jsonobject has the key with value 'data' or the key with value 'error' to distinguish different json.

Comment: Hi I handle that in the first few lines of my code. I try get 'data' if its not there I get null so I check for 'errors'

Comment: oh, sorry for my misunderstanding. but the debug hint right. your element is  "user:["invali.."].  you use element.get("user") to get string "invalid..." ?

Answer (score 0):

Well the debugger got it right, `element.isJsonArray()` is a hint that "user" is indeed JsonArray.

You simply got a `LinkedTreeMap` that is mapping between String keys to values. You give it a key and get a value. The value can be anything. In case of "user" key, the value is `JsonArray`.

Comment: Aye, but how do I get the LinkedTreeMap when my value is JsonElement :S

Comment: You don't. Each value is JSONObject, each JSONObject may have others JSONObjects, that you can obtain them with getVAlue method. Also JSONObject can be JsonArray, to test this condition you do: JSONObject .isJsonArray. And to convert JSONObject to JsonArray you do: JSONObject .getAsJsonArray

Comment: Can I have an example in my case please to get the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code .lets say String responseStr=new JSONObject(jsondat);

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseStr);
    if (response.has("data")) {
        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONObject error = data.getJSONObject("errors");
        JSONArray users = error.getJSONArray("user");
    } else if (response.has("errors")) {
        JSONObject error = response.getJSONObject("errors");
        JSONArray promotion = error.getJSONArray("promotion");
    }
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the confusion, but I meant as an example, it can not just be user or promotion but anything :D

Comment: and i you are getting upper response on success and second response on failur or no record

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my old answer, this is the new one.

Error on my part, see my backend can send data then errors or just data or just errors as the root nodes. I forgot to access data and then errors

This is the working code

@Override
    public APIErrorBody deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String message = ""; /** The error message we are going to display */

```
    /** Backend inconsistency: Unsuccessful response from backend can come with node data -> errors or just errors or just data we must check what is there :S */
    JsonObject dataOrErrorsAsRoot = json.getAsJsonObject();
    if(dataOrErrorsAsRoot.has("data")){ //Check if the first element is data
        dataOrErrorsAsRoot = json.getAsJsonObject().get("data").getAsJsonObject();
        if(dataOrErrorsAsRoot.has("errors")){ //Check if an errors element exists in the data element
            dataOrErrorsAsRoot = dataOrErrorsAsRoot.get("errors").getAsJsonObject();
        }
    }else{ //it must be errors only, but we should check in case a 503 happens and we try deserialise and empty body
        if(dataOrErrorsAsRoot.has("errors")){
            dataOrErrorsAsRoot = json.getAsJsonObject().get("errors").getAsJsonObject();
        }
    }

    if(dataOrErrorsAsRoot != null){
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : dataOrErrorsAsRoot.entrySet()) //Lets loop through each field in the json object we got
        {
            JsonElement element = entry.getValue();
            if(element.isJsonArray()){ //if its an array get each string message and combine it
                JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++){
                    message +=  jsonArray.get(i).getAsString() + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Fail safe, if we got no message or no json just return some generic message
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(message)){
        message = MyApplication.getInstance().getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_error);
    }

    APIErrorBody apiErrorBody = new APIErrorBody();
    apiErrorBody.setErrorMessageToDisplay(message);
    return apiErrorBody;
}
```